# Libre Base form - selecting and printing multiple records

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I created a form in LibreOffice Base and its data is connected to the tables within Base. I also created a button. When I select a record with the form and then click the button, the data gets printed.

I'm using a macro which selects a Writer as template with mail merge of that database and prints a document with the data from a currently selected record form Base forms.

How do I select multiple records and print them instead of just one?

Comment: Well the short answer is you'll have to rewrite your macro.  It will need to produce the data from a query (in macro code), and then send to whereever.  It might be good to start by posting the macro code you're currently using.